# How to crop a picture in MS Office 2013 environment?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I have upgraded the MS Office to Office 2013, now I have a problem of how to crop a picture.
Before, in Office 2010, there was "Office Picture Manager" which was very helpful tool to manage your picture, for example cropping pictures.

Now, How I can crop a picture?

I have tried this: copying a picture to MS PowerPoint and crop it, then save it again. This  will reduce the quality of the picture, so I do not recommend that.

Comment: Do you mean picture edit in document/workbook or do you look for a tool to manage pictures?
Please edit question so I can help.

Comment: @AcePL I am looking for a tool so that I can edit pictures without affecting the picture quality.

Comment: See to my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I saw suggested methods, I realized that it is better to install "Office Picture Manager" in Office 2010 only. This has solved the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Before, in Office 2010, there was "Office Picture Manager" ...

This is basically the same in Office 2013, e.g. [in Word 2013](http://www.computerforall.ca/microsoft-office/86-office-2013/word-2013/144-how-to-crop-a-picture-into-a-shape-in-microsoft-word-2013):

• First of all you need to insert a picture that you want to crop ,for inserting a picture

Go to Insert Tab

Choose to insert picture by 2 options: Picture and Online picture

[image]

After locating your picture to the proper location ,Go to picture tools tab which will be enable by selecting your picture

[image]

Choose crop from Size group, and then choose crop to shape and choose a shape that you want your picture crop to that shape

[image]

Comment: not really an answer to question, if I understand it correctly... ;) Office Picture Manager is a standalone tool to manage pictures in a fashion similar to ACDsee, for example. And that tool has been replaced with Windows Essentials accessible through Photo Gallery...

Comment: @AcePL: It that not the valid way to crop a picture in MS Office 2013 environment?

Comment: Certainly is. But the question was... imprecise, shall we say?

Answer (score 0):

1. In document/workbook:

Method A.

Right-click on image, select Format Picture and then, on the ight there are buttons in the window "Format Picture". Select last icon under that caption and crop will be there

Method B.

Right click on image and there should be two icons UNDER the last option ("Format Picture"), one of them will be Crop

2. In Windows.

Open image in Photo Gallery, navigate to the file to be cropped, double-click on it. Crop option is available then on the top toolbar.